# Pdf of transformation using Jacobian

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not sure what I did wrong using Jacobian method.

The question was: Given two continuous RV $X_1, X_2$ such that $f(x_1, x_2) = 1$ where $0 < x_1, x_2 < 1$. Find pdf of $Z = X_1 + X_2$.

Using CDF method, I arrive at $f(z) = z$ if $0 < z < 1$, $f(z) = 2 - z$ if $1 \leq z < 2$ and 0 otherwise.

However, when I use Jacobian method with $W = X_2$, then $|J| = 1$. So I only arrive at $f(z) = z$ for $0 < z < 2$. I am not sure how the piecewise function can come in during Jacobian method since I basically just have to substitute in $f(x_1,x_2)$ once.